# WinBioDeleteTemplate function Returns 80098002?

Tags: c#, windows-7, biometrics, credential-providers

i am programming in c# to develop WBF FMA(Windows Biometric Framework  Fingerprint management application).

i am using `WinBioDeleteTemplate()` function to delete a template.it works fine most times.

But sometimes it returns 80098002 returncode.

After i restart the system,it works fine.

So,what is an issue?
How to i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error suggests that The unit ID number does not correspond to a valid biometric device. You are possibly passing an invalid unit id to WinBioDeleteTemplate() and that is why you are receiving this error.